# R - Efficiently counting number of switches in binary variable for each group

Tags: r

To give some context, I have a dataframe of eyetracking data from a psychology experiment and I want to count the switches between two Areas Of Interest (AOI), for each participant.

Here's a simplified dataframe of the problem (we assume that `AOI2 == !AOI1` so we don't need it):

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble(Participant = rep(1:7, times = 1, each = 10),
             Time = rep(1:10, 7),
             AOI1 = rbinom(70, 1, .5))
```

What I want is to count how many times the value of `AOI1` changes during time for each participant. I could do it using `for` loops like bellow, but I was wondering if there was a simpler and more R way of doing it?

```
df.switches <- tibble(Participant = 1:7,
                      Switches = NA)
for(p in 1:7){
  s <- 0
  for(i in 2:10){
    if(subset(df, Participant == p & Time == i, select = AOI1) !=
       subset(df, Participant == p & Time == i-1, select = AOI1)){
      s <- s + 1
    }
  }
  df.switches <- df.switches %>%
    mutate(Switches = ifelse(Participant == p, s, Switches))
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are already using the `tidyverse`, you can use `lag` available as part of `dplyr`. This checks whether the value of AOI1 is the same as the previous value, and if not, sets a flag to 1. For the first record of each participant, the value is automatically set to `NA`. Note that the `group_by` is required, otherwise the flag won't get "reset" every time a new participant is encountered. Also it is assumed that the data is sorted by Participant and Time; if not, pipe `arrange(Participant, Time)` before the `group_by`.

```
df <- tibble(Participant = rep(1:7, times = 1, each = 10),
             Time = rep(1:10, 7),
             AOI1 = rbinom(70, 1, .5))
df2 <- df %>%
  group_by(Participant) %>%
  mutate(switch = ifelse(AOI1 != lag(AOI1), 1, 0)) %>%
  summarise(num_switches = sum(switch, na.rm = TRUE))
```

Comment: That's great, `lag` is just what I needed! Good to know about `arrange` as well, don't need it right now but it sure will come in handy at some point.

Answer (score 5):

One option is to use `dplyr::lag` to compare the value with current row in order to count number of switches for each participants.

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% group_by(Participant) %>%
  summarise(count = sum(AOI1 != lag(AOI1, default = -Inf)))

# # A tibble: 7 x 2
#   Participant count
#         <int> <int>
# 1           1     5
# 2           2     4
# 3           3     5
# 4           4     4
# 5           5     6
# 6           6     6
# 7           7     4
```